# opencv cant write video from camera on python

Tags: python, opencv

im trying to save a video i get from a facetime camera on mac, i manage to show the video and flip it, but when i try to save it i get no file at all, and it wont show me any error, it did use to show me an error ***CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file):*** that it was a codec error related, i installed ffmpeg as sugested on other post and i did set the codec to mp4v, still i cant write the file, i do want to write it to a file and then broadcast via web (security camera)

any idea what might be wrong? i paste my code below, thanks

here is the code im using

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#import PyQt5
#from matplotlib import pyplot as pl

#hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
#hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
#cv2.startWindowThread()

def inc_brig(cuadro, value):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(cuadro, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)
    lim = 255 - value
    v[v > lim ] = 255
    v[v <= lim] += value
    #cv2.add(hsv[:,:,2], value, hsv[:,:,2])
    final_hsv = cv2.merge((h,s,v))
    cuadro = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    return cuadro


i = 0
for i in range(4):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)  # start the camera
    if not cap:
        pass
    else:
        print('found at ' + str(i))
        break
    
#check if the camera has been initialized
if cap.isOpened():
    pass
else:
    cap.open()
    
videocodec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
salida = cv2.VideoWriter('prueba_video.mp4', videocodec, 24.0, (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4)) ) )#(int(cap.get(3)), int((cap.get(4)))))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        print ('no frame')
    else:
        if ret == True:
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            frame = inc_brig(frame, 40)            
            #detect people
#            boxes, weight = hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(8,8))
            #return coordinates for people boxes
#            boxes = np.array( [[x, y, x+w, y+h] for (x, y, w, h) in boxes ])
            
#            for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in boxes:
                #display boxes in color picture
#                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (255,0,0), 2)
            #frame = cv2.line(frame,(200,20),(511,511),(220,0,0),5)  # draw lines
            #fuente = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
            #cv2.putText(frame,'Prueba motherfucker', (300,90), fuente, 1, (255,255,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            #frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (300,100), (800,600), (200,0,0), 3)
            salida.write(frame)     #write to file
            
            cv2.imshow('Camara opencv', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

cap.release()
salida.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# show image using matplot
# imagen = cv2.imread('Test_Xv.jpg',0)
# pl.imshow(imagen, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')
# pl.xticks([]), pl.yticks([])
# pl.show()

# show image using standart opencv window
# cv2.imshow('image',imagen)
# k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
# if k == 27:
#     cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# else:
#     cv2.imwrite('Test_Gray.jpg', imagen)
#     cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Edit1: i did follow Christof advice and be more especific when opening the device, still i get the same behaivior i would try also using a debugger and see where the problem is, below is my new code

```
#check if the camera has been initialized
i = 0
for i in range(4):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(i)  # start the camera
    if cap.isOpened():
        print('found at ' + str(i))
        break
    if cap.isOpened() == False:
        cap.open()
        print('opening camera ' + str(i))
        break
```

Edit2: simplyfied the code and set only first device i only get 0 anyway, heres my code using if not cap.isOpened()

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # start the camera
videocodec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
salida = cv2.VideoWriter('prueba_video.mp4', videocodec, 24.0, (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4)) ) )#(int(cap.get(3)), int((cap.get(4)))))

if not cap.isOpened():
    print('not open')
else:
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if frame is None:
            print ('no frame')
        else:
            if ret == True:
                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
                frame = inc_brig(frame, 30)   
                salida.write(frame)     #write to file
                cv2.imshow('Camara opencv', frame)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                   break
            else:
                break

    cap.release()
    salida.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Edit3: posting the general config for opencv on my machine, i did installed using pip command from terminal but before that i updated homebrew, for some reason homebrew erased all previuos stuff i had installed via pip so i had to reinstall opencv, wheels and all other stuff, im posting my modules as well

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.6.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2022-08-16T23:32:48Z
    Host:                        Darwin 17.7.0 x86_64
    CMake:                       3.24.0
    CMake generator:             Ninja
    CMake build tool:            /usr/local/bin/ninja
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1
      requested:                 DETECT
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (31 files):           + POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++  (ver 10.0.0.10001044)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,-dead_strip  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,-dead_strip  
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          -framework OpenCL /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework -lm -ldl -framework Cocoa -framework AppKit
    3rdparty dependencies:       libprotobuf ade ittnotify libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf zlib quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI:                           COCOA
    Cocoa:                       YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.12)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.2-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      NO
      avcodec:                   NO
      avformat:                  NO
      avutil:                    NO
      swscale:                   NO
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    AVFoundation:                YES

  Parallel framework:            GCD

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   /private/var/folders/l9/04v9rl9d67q6pyg1n0jyjj9r0000gn/T/pip-install-mkqzz7zw/opencv-python_36a66675c7174c558792570d56da2f92/_skbuild/macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_mac/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                /private/var/folders/l9/04v9rl9d67q6pyg1n0jyjj9r0000gn/T/pip-install-mkqzz7zw/opencv-python_36a66675c7174c558792570d56da2f92/_skbuild/macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.10/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_mac/iw
    Lapack:                      YES (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework -lm -ldl)
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.4.0)
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                NO
    Link libraries:              -framework OpenCL

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_1/bin/python3.10 (ver 3.10.6)
    Libraries:                   /usr/local/opt/python@3.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/libpython3.10.dylib (ver 3.10.6)
    numpy:                       /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.23.2)
    install path:                python/cv2/python-3

  Python (for build):            /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /private/var/folders/l9/04v9rl9d67q6pyg1n0jyjj9r0000gn/T/pip-install-mkqzz7zw/opencv-python_36a66675c7174c558792570d56da2f92/_skbuild/macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.10/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

this are the modules installed by python via terminal

```
Package         Version
--------------- --------
cmake           3.24.0
cycler          0.11.0
Cython          0.29.32
distro          1.7.0
ffmpeg          1.4
ffmpeg-python   0.2.0
fonttools       4.35.0
future          0.18.2
kiwisolver      1.4.4
matplotlib      3.5.3
numpy           1.23.2
opencv-python   4.6.0.66
packaging       21.3
Pillow          9.2.0
pip             22.2.2
protobuf        4.21.5
pyparsing       3.0.9
python-dateutil 2.8.2
scikit-build    0.15.0
setuptools      63.4.3
six             1.16.0
TBB             0.2
wheel           0.37.1
```

Comment: run your code in a debugger. watch what it does. since you don't even know where it fails, you must do that.

Comment: sadly i have no idea how to use the python debugger on vscode, ill check how thanks

Comment: once again: `if not cap.isOpened()`, trying to call `cap.open()` is **futile**. if it *could* have opened the device during object construction, it *would* have. it is silly to try again. your loop breaks regardless on the first iteration. and setting `i = 0` before the loop is entirely pointless too

Comment: ok i did follow your advice and went simple, set the device with **`cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`** then keep the loop on **`while(cap.isOpened()):`** removed also all other functions just in case, still the same problem, used the debugger but i dont see the write functions is called at all, i did try **`out = salida.write(frame)`** but i cant get anything from that, any idea? the video is shown on screen, just wont write the file

Comment: ah! so the video is shown on screen! good to know! what's the value of `salida.isOpened()`?

Comment: Its False, thats the bugger, **salida.isOpened()** returns False all the time, no mather where i place it, before or after the loop

Comment: ok good, now I know where the issue is. please add the output of `print(cv2.getBuildInformation())` (at least the Video I/O section) to your question. I'm wondering whether your OpenCV was built with ffmpeg support or not. if not, that'll limit you to `.avi` container and `MJPG` codec. -- fourccs are case-sensitive. `"MP4V" != "mp4v"`, so try that

Comment: oooohkay no ffmpeg. I'm unfamiliar with avfoundation and how much of it OpenCV can use. _maybe_ that's just for video cameras. then that means you're left with `.avi` container and `MJPG` codec.

Comment: ok ill check if theres anyway to set ffmpg support, also i dont know if i mention this, this is running on mac, but the main idea is to run it on RPi3, save to file and broadcast it as a security camera, i preffer to have my own camera than some ramdon one with a foreign server

Comment: if it's gonna run on a raspi, you needn't worry. that build of `opencv-python` _very likely_ has ffmpeg support. I'd recommend `.ts` (MPEG transport stream) container then, because if writing suddenly stops (process killed or anything), those files are still readable. `.mp4` files, when they have *not* been finalized (`writer.release()`), are simply unreadable and all but unrecoverable. I can't be sure how that works for `.avi` files.

Comment: thanks a lot this actually was the solution to my problem not sure how to set it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiation of a `VideoWriter` appears to have failed. You say `salida.isOpened()` returns `False`.

`VideoWriter` usually requires that OpenCV was built with support for ffmpeg. Other backends, such as AVFoundation, commonly are only used to access video cameras.

Since your OpenCV was built *without* support for ffmpeg, your only option is to use the `.avi` video container format and the `MJPG` codec/fourcc. Those two are built into OpenCV and always available.

If you haven't already got OpenCV for Python from PyPI, via the `opencv-python` package (or one of its variants), then you should try that. It's the **official** OpenCV package for Python.

If you are willing to build OpenCV yourself, you can enable and disable features, and third-party dependencies, in the CMake configuration stage.

Comment: plz check edit one with new code, also im checking the debugger, thanks